# O que é um sistema tolerante à falhas (fault tolerance)?

Tags: terminologia, arquitetura-de-software

Ao falar de sistemas de alta escala, muito se ouve de ter um sistema tolerante à falhas (*fault-tolerant*). Veja na descrição da linguagem de programação Elixir:

> Elixir é construído no topo da VM do Erlang, conhecida por rodar sistemas de baixa latência, distribuídos e **tolerantes à falhas**, enquanto também ter tido sucesso no desenvolvimento *web* e sistemas embarcados. [adaptado e traduzido de [elixir-lang.org](https://elixir-lang.org)]

Mas não entendi o que significa um sistema ter essa característica. Quer dizer que o sistema pode se auto-recuperar de falhas? Que tipo de falhas devem ser cobertas para que um sistema seja tolerante à falhas? E quais estratégias são utilizadas para um sistema ser tolerante à falhas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É uma característica de sistemas que são capazes de continuar operando de forma mais ou menos normal independentemente de haver falhas em alguma das partes necessárias para seu funcionamento.

A forma de obter essa característica varia, e pode envolver soluções de hardware ou software. Quase sempre a tolerância é obtida com algum sistema reserva, replicação, espelhamento, redundância, ou algo do tipo, e, em geral, também conta com algum tipo de monitoramento e escalonamento de ações quando há algo errado. Mas uma forma de ajudar é escrever códigos que sejam robustos, que sempre estejam preparados para que uma falha ocorra e consigam fazer algo útil com isso. Mas lembre-se que muitas vezes a tolerância se dará pela infraestrutura adotada.

Em soluções de software costuma-se antecipar à problemas e não deixá-los acontecer ou depois de ocorrido ter algum caminho que permita reexecutar ou partir para outra forma que entregue o resultado desejado. Um simples sistema que detecte erros no software e dê uma solução já pode ser considerado tolerante a falhas em algum nível. Geralmente só usamos o termo quando tudo é resolvido sem uma intervenção direta de humanos.

Em geral essa tolerância é um pouco limitada e em cada situação é explicitado em quais casos a operação pode continuar normal. É óbvio que sempre tem níveis falhas e quanto mais tolerante a todo tipo de falha o sistema precisa ser, mais complexo será, em alguns casos só podem ser tolerantes com muita replicação em partes do mundo. Em outros só ter uma forma de resolver se um dos softwares da solução falhar outra resolve o trabalho ou dá algum resultado útil assim mesmo.

Por isso o termo é muito usado como marketing quando não específica o nível de tolerância.

Não há garantias que a tolerância permita operação normal sempre, apenas que não pare totalmente. Em alguns casos entregar o resultado nem é a intenção, só não parar de funcionar já é um bom objetivo.

É importante que qualquer coisa errada que ocorra no meio do processo de falha que possa ser revertido ou que possa ser contido sem contaminar outras partes.

Alguns mecanismos são bem sofisticados, complexos e caros.

Não existem ferramentas que fazem isso de forma mágica como alguns possam querer. Claro, você pode contratar algum serviço que te dê algo pronto, mas jamais obterá isso sem esforço grande de alguém.

Por tudo isso é complicado falar em tipos de falhas e estratégias específicas, cada solução se dá de uma forma de acordo com cada tipo de sistema.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Fault tolerance é a capacidade de um sistema continuar a funcionar corretamente em caso de falhas em componentes ou erros.

Isso é alcançado através da redundância de componentes, backup de dados, detecção de falhas e recuperação de erros. O objetivo é garantir a disponibilidade e a confiabilidade do sistema mesmo em condições adversas.

### Sistemas tolerantes a falhas podem se recuperar sozinhos?

Depende. Alguns sistemas tolerante a falhas possuem capacidade de auto-recuperação, ou seja, são capazes de detectar e corrigir erros sem intervenção humana. Por exemplo, em sistemas de armazenamento em cluster, se um disco falhar, o sistema pode automaticamente usar uma cópia redundante dos dados para recuperar o sistema sem a necessidade de intervenção humana.

No entanto, outros sistemas tolerante a falhas podem precisar de intervenção humana para recuperação, por exemplo, em caso de falhas em componentes críticos ou erros que exigem decisões humanas para correção. Nestes casos, a recuperação pode ser manual ou automatizada, mas requer intervenção humana para iniciar o processo.

### Exemplos de sistemas tolerante a falhas incluem:

- Sistemas de armazenamento em cluster, onde vários discos são usados em conjunto para tolerar falhas em discos individuais.
- Sistemas de computação em nuvem, que usam redundância de hardware e software para tolerar falhas em servidores ou outros componentes.
- Sistemas de energia elétrica, que usam redundância de geradores e outros componentes para manter a energia elétrica disponível mesmo quando há falhas.
- Sistemas de transporte, como aeronaves com dupla propulsão e sistemas de backup de instrumentos para tolerar falhas em componentes críticos

### Que tipo de falhas devem ser cobertas para que um sistema seja tolerante à falhas?

Para ser considerado tolerante a falhas, um sistema deve ser projetado para lidar com uma ampla gama de falhas, incluindo:

- Falhas de hardware: como falhas em discos rígidos, memórias, processadores, entre outros componentes.
- Falhas de software: como bugs, erros de programação, falhas em sistemas operacionais, entre outros.
- Falhas na rede: como perda de conexão, interrupções, congestionamento, entre outros.
- Falhas humanas: como erros de operação, descuidos, entre outros.
- Relacionar o item

Além disso, é importante considerar que um sistema tolerante a falhas deve ser projetado para lidar com falhas em diferentes graus de severidade, desde falhas menores que podem ser corrigidas rapidamente até falhas maiores que exigem mais tempo e esforço para recuperação. O objetivo é garantir a disponibilidade e a confiabilidade do sistema mesmo em condições adversas.

### E quais estratégias são utilizadas para um sistema ser tolerante à falhas?

1. Redundância: uso de componentes ou sistemas duplicados para tolerar falhas em componentes ou sistemas individuais.
2. Backup de dados: cópias redundantes de dados para uso em caso de falhas em componentes ou sistemas
3. Detecção de falhas: monitoramento constante do sistema para detectar e notificar falhas rapidamente.
4. Recuperação de falhas: planos e processos para corrigir rapidamente falhas no sistema.
5. Balanceamento de carga: distribuição equilibrada da carga de trabalho entre vários componentes ou sistemas para minimizar a impacto de falhas.

Isolamento de falhas: separação lógica ou física de componentes ou sistemas para evitar que falhas em um componente ou sistema afetem o funcionamento geral do sistema.

### Como definimos falhas em sistemas distribuídos?

- **Falhas transientes:** Acontecem uma única vez em uma janela de tempo, não sendo detectadas novamente. Falhas transientes são difíceis de serem tratadas pois dificilmente teremos a repetição do contexto que possibilita a detecção delas.
- **Falhas intermitentes:** Diferente das falhas transientes, as intermitentes reaparecem com alguma frequência. Um exemplo de falhas intermitentes são problemas de perda de pacotes causados por hardwares com problemas em sua rede, causando inconsistência nas mensagens.
- **Falhas permanentes:** São aquelas que uma vez iniciadas, elas não vão embora até que haja uma ação específica de tratamento contra elas. Um exemplo clássico são bugs em código que causam o consumo indiscriminado de memória até que haja o esgotamento da memória RAM, derrubando a instância do serviço.

Fonte: [Falhas em Sistemas Distribuídos - Código 35](https://codigo35.com/2022/05/31/falhas-em-sistemas-distribuidos/)